# Exclude files listed in '.hidden' when using 'ls'

Tags: terminal, ls, hidden-files

In my home folder, I have a file called '.hidden' in which I put the names of a few files and folders that I don't want to see in that directory. I can't change their names, ie: I *can't* put the dot '.' at the beginning.

When I give 'ls' in a terminal, it lists all files and folders including those listed in '.hidden'. I want 'ls' to exclude them.

Is there a way for doing this?

I have to pass the ***content*** of the file '.hidden' to ls. Something like:

```
ls --ignore= [SOME MAGIC HERE] $(tr '\n' ' ' < .hidden)
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

```
alias ls='exclusion=; while read p ; do exclusion=$exclusion" -I$p"; done < ~/.hidden; ls $exclusion --color=auto --group-directories-first'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got another solution! `sed`, `tr`, and `xargs` to the rescue!

```sh
alias ls="sed 's/^/-I \"/' .hidden 2>/dev/null | sed 's/$/\"/' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs ls --color=auto"
```